# A to Z list of posts with Pagination for Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

## Thanks for taking an intrest

I am looking for some to provide a clear, good practice, example (or link to an existing one) of how to **create an A to Z list of posts with Pagination for Custom Post Type** in the latest version of **Wordpress** based on the scenario below.

There are two existing questions I have found on this site but neither answer the question clearly or definitively.

To keep things simple for me to explain the scenario and for those responding.  I am basing my explanation around a website all about Fruit.  When trying to use the answers given I am hoping this will be easy for I and other learners to follow the replys and intergrate it into their own code.

## Basic Structure

- I have created a *Custom Post Type* called "*Fruits*".
- I have created a series of *Posts* within Fruits, each with a *Post Title*
  of a particular fruit e.g. "Bananas".
- I have created a *Page Template* within which is the following div:`<div id="MyAtoZArea" class="MyAtoZStyle"></div>`.

## Output

- Within the div I would like code that will display a list of all the
  posts in the custom post type "Fruits".
- I would like to wrap the output in an unordered list `<ul>` with each title being a different list item `<li>`
- I would like the list to be sorted alphabetically by the Post Title.
- As each letter of the Alphabet changes I would like it to be inserted. For example:

**A** 
Apples 
Apricots 
**B** 
Bananas

- I would like for letters of the alphabet not to be shown if there are no applicable posts.  For example:

**A** 
Apples 
**K** 
Kiwi 
**S** 
Strawberrys

- Finally I would like to show a maximum of 20 posts, using pagination to show the next 20 and so on.

## Can you help? If so post below.

All constructive guidance and comments are welcome.

Comment: clarify how pagination should work. Should it paginate after 20 posts alphabetically or should it be like A: [posts1-18] B [post19-20] -> new Page C[...]

Comment: Hi Niklas, For me Pagination should work 20 posts alphabetically e.g. Fruits: Page 1 (posts 1-20) Page 2 (posts 21-40) Page 3 (posts 41-60) but if you have an example of Fruits: Page 1 (all A posts) Page 2 (all B posts) Page 3 (all C posts) I am sure other may find it useful.  I have been searching for a good couple of days without sucess in finding a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like below. The following code you should post in your template:

```
<?php
//get the posts first
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
     'paged' => $paged,
     'posts_per_page' => 20,
     'post_type' => 'fruits',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'orderby' => 'title'
);
$fruits = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<ul>
<?php
//loop through all the posts in the custom query
if( $fruits->have_posts() ) {
  $current_first_letter = '';

  while($fruits->have_posts() ) {
    $fruits->the_post();
    $title = the_title();
    if (is_string($title)) {
        $first_letter = $title[0]   
        //output a first letter list item with a custom class to be styled differently in your css if it is a new first letter     
        if ($first_letter != $current_first_letter) {
            echo '<li class="divider"'> . strtoupper($first_letter) . '</li>';
            $current_first_letter = $first_letter;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
    <?php
  }
}
?>
</ul>

//pagination
<?php if ($fruits->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1  ?>
  <nav class="prev-next-posts">
    <div class="prev-posts-link">
      <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $fruits->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?>
    </div>
    <div class="next-posts-link">
      <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); // display newer posts link ?>
    </div>
  </nav>
<?php } ?>

//restore original post data
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

You could easyly alter your code to also display labels for letters without posts

Answer (score 0):

Please use this below code. The following code you should use in your post type template: it's really work for me... I have also tested this code.... See screenshots 1. http://prntscr.com/dxzi22 (full A to Z) 2. http://prntscr.com/dxziih (Full A to Z with Pagination)... you need do to some CSS for that...

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('paged' => $paged,'posts_per_page' => -1,'post_type' => 'services','post_status' => 'publish','orderby' => 'title','order' => 'asc');
$fruits = new WP_Query($args);
if($fruits->have_posts()){
  $current_first_letter = '';
  $t = array();
  $s = array();
  while($fruits->have_posts()){
    $fruits->the_post();
    $title = get_the_title();
    if(is_string($title)){
        $first_letter = strtoupper($title[0]); 
        if($first_letter != $current_first_letter){
            $t[] = $first_letter;
            $current_first_letter = $first_letter;
        }
    }
    $s[$first_letter][] = get_the_title();
  }
}

$t = array_unique($t);
$tc = count($t);
$sc = count($s);
for($i=0; $i<$tc; $i++){
    ?>
    <div>
        <h4><?php echo $t[$i]; ?></h4>
        <ul>
        <?php
        foreach($s as $key => $value){
            if($key == $t[$i]){
                $vc = count($value);
                for($j=0; $j<$vc; $j++){
        ?>
            <li><?php echo $value[$j]; ?></li>
        <?php
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
}
if($fruits->max_num_pages > 1){ ?>
  <nav class="prev-next-posts">
    <div class="prev-posts-link">
      <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $fruits->max_num_pages ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="next-posts-link">
      <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?>
    </div>
  </nav>
<?php } ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```